# Need advice on solving System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x88982F72)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, com

We're getting this weird exception when trying to create a BitmapDecoder off an ASP.Net response stream.  This is the line of code that throws the exception:

```
BitmapDecoder dec = BitmapDecoder.Create(
    Request.Files[0].InputStream, 
    BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, 
    BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
```

Here's some info on the file being uploaded:

> Filename: bank statement.jpg, Content length: 266041, Mime type: image/jpeg

This is the exception stack trace:

```
System.IO.IOException: Cannot read from the stream. ---> 
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x88982F72): 
    Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F72
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid& clsId, Boolean& isOriginalWritable, Stream& uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream& unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle& safeFilehandle)
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy, Boolean insertInDecoderCache)
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.Create(Stream bitmapStream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how we can prevent this from happening?

Comment: did you try this one: http://forums.asp.net/p/1219504/2171553.aspx ?

Comment: This isn't an RPC, and the COM HRESULT is different..

Comment: Also, it doesn't happen everytime.  A few times a day, out of a hundred successful uploads.

Comment: Can't you save the file locally first in temp folder and use it in BitmapDecoder. Is bitmapdecoder is your component?

Comment: Sry I read your response after I posted it. Is it possible that sometimes stream closed/break before upload completed and so it breaks from reading in halfway. What do you think?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce the issue on my local machine.

Comment: That's possible, Manish.  Any ideas on how I can reproduce that?  If so, submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x88982f72 is actually WINCODEC_ERR_STREAMREAD (from [Codec Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719669%28VS.85%29.aspx)), which indeed is "Cannot read from the stream".

If the stream is coming in from "the wild world" (aka: the Internet), it maybe mean that it's ...just garbage or a hack tentative. If your own tests work fine and don't exhibit this problem, I think it's fair to just handle this specific error and fail gracefully.